# Oracle AUDSID equivalent in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, audit

What is the equivalent SQL Server 2012 code for this please ?

```
 IF INSERTING THEN
            :NEW.audsid:=SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SESSIONID');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle and SQL Server handle triggers very differently.  Oracle has the concept that a trigger affects only one row at a time. SQL Server doesn't. Instead, it uses a "table" `inserted` with the new rows.

So, your question has three parts:

1. What is the equivalent of `INSERTED`?
2. What is the equivalent of `SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SESSIONID')`?
3. What is the best way to do this in SQL Server?

Here is the answer to the first two questions:

```
if (exists (select 1 from inserted) and (not exists (select 1 from deleted))
    update inserted
        set audsid = @@SPID;
```

However, in most cases, you would just use the `default` keyword in the column definition:

```
audsid int default @@SPID
```

Much easier and a trigger isn't needed.

Comment: +1 for the fact - and I know I'm awfully nit-picky - but `SQL` is just the query language (used *also* by Oracle) - while what you refer to is really **SQL Server** - the Microsoft RDBMS product, which has a different trigger behavior than Oracle.

Comment: I am not familiar with Oracle's trigger handling and trying to convert many such triggers in SQL Server 2012 .

Comment: it is absolutely right that I might just use `audsid int default @@SPID` but i also have to check updation so trigger is needed for those case ....am I correct ? If i update the row/rows then the `default` value won't change to the current session id right ?

Comment: @user3844877 . . . In that case, I think you would need a trigger.